# rosjava.android overrides interface functions

Tags: ros, android-teleop, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully installed and built both rosjava and rosjava.android.

I add android_gingerbread, android_honeycomb_mr2 and android_tutorial_teleop to an eclipse project.

android_gingerbread throws 40 errors complaining that the Method X must override a superclass method. Upon inspection each of these methods has an @Override for an interface. It is my understanding that you do not @Override interface classes, so I am confused why it is overriding to begin with. I tried going through and changing each interface into class, fixing the function, and making android_gingerbread extend them instead of implement, but some of the classes are android libraries I cannot change.
android_honeycomb_mr2 also throws around 80 of the same errors.

Is the solution just to remove all of the @override's? Or is there something else going on here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32028/rosjava.android-overrides-interface-functions/) by [Jyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2115/jyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2012-04-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The use of the `@Override` annotation changed between Java 1.5 and Java 1.6 with respect to implementing interface methods. In Eclipse, check Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Compiler Compliance Level; set that to 1.6. You might check the project-specific settings as well, under the main Java Compiler page.

There is some more information available at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2335655/why-is-javac-failing-on-override-annotation).

---

Originally posted by [jatowler](https://answers.ros.org/users/934/jatowler/) with karma: 61 on 2012-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1